# Checking if input values are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a tool that allows users to generate CSS code. At the moment I'm working on input - when a user leaves a text input empty, I'd like a message to appear. The code I have at the moment doesn't seem to work in doing so, any ideas?

```
$("#btn-css").click(function() {
    if( $('input').attr(value) = "" ) {
      $('#output').append('All boxes must be completed');
    } else {
      $('.preview').attr('style', 'box-shadow: ' + $("#h-value").val() + 'px ' + $("#v-value").val() + 'px ' + $("#blur").val() + 'px ' + $("#spread").val() + 'px #' + $("#colour").val() + ';');
      $('#output').append('box-shadow: ' + $("#h-value").val() + 'px ' + $("#v-value").val() + 'px ' + $("#blur").val() + 'px ' + $("#spread").val() + 'px #' + $("#colour").val() + ';');
    }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you use `.val()` instead of `.attr(value)`? (Which is also wrong, because value should be a string)

Answer (score 1):

use `.val()`.. `val()` does the exact same thing you mentioned..

```
if( $('input').val() == "" ) {
```

to check for all input..

```
var inputVallength=$('input').filter(function(){
       return this.value==""
   }).length;

if(inputVallength == 0 || inputVallength < $('input').length){
 $('#output').append('All boxes must be completed');  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this it will select all text inputs on the page then filter them to be the ones that are empty.

```
$("#btn-css").click(function() {
    var emptyInputs = $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
    if (emptyInputs.length === 0) {
        // Everything filled in

    } else {
        $('#output').append('All boxes must be completed');
    }

});
```

You might also want to do:

```
var emptyInputs = $('input:text').filter(function() { return $.trim(this.value) == ""; });
```

This will also pick up text inputs with just whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').attr(value)
```

This selects ALL input elements on the entire page.

And also what @Mike Christensen said, you need at least 2 equal signs.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
$(':input').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        //logic
    }
});
```

[a Quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Tmzu/)